# Type-conditional methods inside generic structures in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, data-structures, polymorphism

Consider the following class:

```
case class Container[A](as: A*){
  def asSeq: Seq[A] = as.toSeq
  def head: A = as.head
  def tail: Container[A] = Container(as.tail)
}

val container = Container(1, 2, 3)
container.head
// res0: 1
```

I can define generic methods inside `Container` without any problems, but now let's suppose I would like to define a conditional method `sum` as `as.sum`. If I attempt to do that, I run into the following error: `no implicits found for parameter num: Numeric[A]`.

How can I create a `sum` method that would work for all numeric types (or at least one such as `Int`)?

Many thanks!

Comment: `def sum(implicit ev: Numeric[A]): A = as.sum` for this specific case, or if you want to check for a specific type: `def sumOnlyInts(implicit ev: A <:< Int): Int = as.sum`

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Just a quick follow up -- why do you use `ev: A <:< Int`?  Shouldn't `ev <: Int` be enough? Also, this doesn't seem to work, I get an error: `no implicits found for parameter num: Numeric[A]`

Comment: Take a look to [this](https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html) blog post to understand what is happening under the hood. And fo fixing that error, this should be enough: `def sumOnlyInts(implicit ev: A <:< Int): Int = as.iterator.map(ev).sum`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link! I'll remember the "sad-with-a-hat" operator from now on :)